# Externalize mongo json query using spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

I have just started using spring data **MongoDb** with **Spring-Boot**.

I have some mongo based json queries added in the interface using @query annotation when using spring data repository.

I want to know if it is possible to **externalize** or **separate** out the JSON query outside the codebase so that it can be optimized separately and

also not having it mixed with code.

Thanks for your suggestions.

This is the code which i have added in my interface and annotated with @query annotation.

@Query("{ 'firstname' : ?0 ,'lastname': ?1}")
  List findByCriteria(String firstname,String lastname);

The above is a simple example. I have complex conditions involving $and and $or operators too .

What i basically want to achieve is externalize the above native mongo json query to a config file and refer that in the above annotation.

Spring data supports something similar when using jpa with hibernate. But not sure if we can do the same using spring data mongodb with spring boot.

Answer (score 1):

Do like this (I am explaining only for the API)

Suppose you have an Entity `user`

At the Top there will be **User domain**

```
public class User extends CoreDomain {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -4292195532570879677L;
@Length(min = 2)
private String name;
@Length(min = 2)
@UniqueUserName(message = "User name already registered,Please choose something Different")
private String userName;
@Length(min = 6)
private String password;
}
```

> User Controller
>
> User Service (Interface)
>
> User ServiceImpl(Service Implementation)
>
> Mongo Repository(Since, I have MongoDb)

Now in **userController** you will take all the `queries` , `Param(Parameters)` , `Pagerequest` like this

```
public class UserController extends CoreController {

@Autowired
private UserService userService;

/*
 * This controller is for getting the UserDetails on passing the UserId in
 * the @param Annotation
 */
@GET
@Path("{id}")
public User getUser(@PathParam("id") String UserId) {
    User user = new User();
    user = userService.findUserId(UserId);

    if (user == null)
        throw new NotFoundException();
    log.info("The userId you searched is having the details as :" + user);
    return user;
}}
```

For **serviceInterface** you will have :

```
public interface UserService {
// Boolean authenticateUser(User user);

User findUserId(String UserId);

}
```

For **serviceImpl** :

```
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
@Setter
@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

/*
 * This method will find user on the basis of their userIds passed in the
 * parameter.
 */
@Override
public User findUserId(String UserId) {
    User userIdResult = userRepository.findOne(UserId);
    log.info("The userDetail is" + userIdResult);
    return userIdResult;
}
```

In **mongoRepository** for `user` we will have: 
    A default query `findById(String userId);`

Hopefully this will help you.

Comment: My question is on how to externalize mongo json queries from code when using @query annotation. I am aware of the support of mongo repositories for basic query support.

Comment: I tried hard to understand your requirement but sorry that this doesn't helped you out, If I will get some more,Will notify you...Thanks